# Можно ли настроить область клика на мобильных девайсах

Tags: javascript, css

Есть чекбокс, с линкой внутри. На мобильнике невозможно поставить галочку, потому что открывается ссылка. Есть ли возможность уменьшить область клика?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эм, а если в квадратик тыкать?

Comment: На телефоне на строку вверх и вниз от линка тяжело найти пиксель который бы чекнул чекбокс, вот уже если на "понятно" кликнуть, то получится

Comment: Ну переделайте ссылку. Оставьте её только на слове «Уведомление» или вообще уберите ссылку из этого блока и поставьте отдельно.